# Navigation bar not showing and not working on click

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have been struggling with this for forever and am hoping to finally figure it out with some help. I'm trying to add a navigation bar to the toolbar on the home screen (Main Activity) of my app. 
Right now, the toolbar is not showing, with the DrawerLayout in my XML and the nav drawer icon also ins't showing. to open the drawer I have to swipe right. Then when I click an item in the drawer the view isn't changed. The 2 item's in the drawers are both fragments. I believe there is an issue in my code as well as my XML, but I'm not good with android XML files.

RobotChooser.java relevant code

```
public class RobotChooser extends AppCompatActivity implements AddEditRobotDialogFragment.DialogListener, ConfirmDeleteDialogFragment.DialogListener, ListView.OnItemClickListener {

private View mEmptyView;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

private ShowcaseView showcaseView;
private boolean addedRobot;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

private String[] mFeatureTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private int drawerIndex = 1;
private String mTitle;
private String mDrawerTitle;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

Fragment fragment;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.robot_chooser);

    mEmptyView = findViewById(R.id.robot_empty_view);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.robot_recycler_view);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.robot_chooser_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    RobotStorage.load(this);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_robot_chooser);
    mFeatureTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chooser_titles); //Where you set drawer item titles
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer2);

    mTitle="ROS Control";
    mDrawerTitle=mTitle;

    if (getActionBar() != null) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    int[] imgRes = new int[]{
            R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp
    };

    List<DrawerItem> drawerItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mFeatureTitles.length; i++) {
        drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(mFeatureTitles[i], imgRes[i]));
    }

    NavDrawerAdapter drawerAdapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(this,
            R.layout.nav_drawer_menu_item,
            drawerItems);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    private void selectItem(int position){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    switch (position) {
        case 0:

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return;

        case 1:
            fragment = new PreferencesFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment)
                    .commit();
            //fragmentsCreatedCounter = 0

            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            //fragmentsCreatedCounter = fragmentsCreatedCounter + 1;
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment)
                    .commit();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    setTitle(mFeatureTitles[position]);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    try {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Ignore
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selectItem(position);
```

robot_chooser.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/robot_chooser_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_robot_chooser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/hud_fragment"
        android:name="com.robotca.ControlApp.Fragments.PreferencesFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64sp"/>
    <!--tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hud"-->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/about_fragment"
        android:name="com.robotca.ControlApp.Fragments.AboutFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about"/>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/robot_recycler_view"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/robot_empty_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/no_robots"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ddd"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using android studio? create demo with inbuilt template and compare that code with yours. you can do that in eclipse also.

Comment: Yes I'm using android studio. I think the big problem is my xml and also how I make the fragment clicked in the drawer set to be the new screen seen

Answer (score 0):

xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/profileDrawer"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/robot_chooser_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/robot_recycler_view"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/robot_empty_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/no_robots"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer2"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

then in the switch cases 1 and 2, you need to hide the recycler view like so

```
mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```